# Populate Label in VB from MySQL select query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have found a few articles that are similar to my question, and I have tried the suggestions in those articles and none of them have worked for me. What I need seems to be fairly simple and straight forward. (I am able to complete this same action with SQL Server, just not with MySQL. This 'description' information must come a MySQL db)

I have a Listbox and as the user clicks on listbox items, I would like a 'description' label to update with a value pulled from a MySQL database.

I created a public sub in the Module, and I'm calling the sub from the Listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged event (also tried Listbox1_mouseclick event).

However, everything I have tried does not update the label. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code being used to pull and attempt to populate the label:

```vb
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(My.Resources.MySqlstr)

Try
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select Description from resourceaccess where tid = '" & ReportPicker.ListBox1.ValueMember & "' ", conn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While reader.Read()
        ReportPicker.Label3.Text = reader.GetString("Description")

    End While

    reader.Close()

Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Please refer to this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314920/putting-result-from-sql-statement-into-label

Comment: You should not be using a data reader and a loop there.  You should be calling `ExecuteScalar`, which is specifically for retrieving a single value.

Comment: I'm looking for a MySQL solution. this article is referencing SQL Server, correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314920/putting-result-from-sql-statement-into-label

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if something else is wrong too but this definitely is:

```vb
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select Description from resourceaccess where tid = '" & ReportPicker.ListBox1.ValueMember & "' ", conn)
```

Apart from the fact that you should be using a parameter there, the use of `ValueMember` can't possibly be right.  That's the name of a column, not a value from that column.  You should be using `SelectedValue`, which is the value from that column for the item that's selected.

Answer (score -1):

here is what worked:

```
    Dim cs As String = My.Resources.MySqlstr

    Dim stm As String = "select Description from resourceaccess where resource = '" & ReportPicker.ListBox1.Text & "' "
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(cs)

    Try
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stm, conn)

        ReportPicker.Label3.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Crazy-vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, while I am a proponent of always using parameters, SQL injection is actually less likely in this scenario than most because it's the `Text` of a `ListBox` being used.  It would be harder for a malicious user to get appropriate SQL into that code than, say, direct input to a `TextBox`. It may still be possible though and if you just use parameters all the time then you never have to worry that you may have chosen not to when you shouldn't have.

Comment: If that was the change you needed to make and you had other code working for SQL Server then you must not have actually compared this code to that properly before posting and you certainly must not have debugged.  If you had debugged then you'd have seen that `ReportPicker.ListBox1.ValueMember` didn't contain the value you needed.  ALWAYS debug before posting a question.  If you don't know how to debug using breakpoints and stepping through code, now would be the time to learn.